# Determine if line is date, string or int in python

Tags: python

My code reads all lines in a textfile and determines if it is a string, int or date.. The problem is reading if it is a datetime.. If I tried to convert it into a datetime object from a string it raises the error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        from datetime import datetime
        try:
            int(line)
            print "This is an integer"
        except:
            try:
                date_object = datetime.strptime(line, '%m-%d-%Y')
                print date_object
                del date_object
                print "This is a date"
            except:
                print "This is a string"
```

My textfile contains:

```
1
John Doe
08-15-2016
```

Comment: Could you include the full error?

Comment: This code works fine for me on Python 2.7. Are you sure the error isn't triggering on code outside of the block you've provided?

Comment: Try trimming the line (remove whitespace at end) first.

Comment: How do you know when a number or date-like piece of text should be handled as a string instead?

Comment: The last entry cannot be a date in many parts of the world, as there are only 12 months in a year. To prevent ambiguity always use year-month-day format when working with string based date data in computers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like You forgot to remove '\n'. You can modify a line as below :-

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(line.strip(), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

I hope it will solve the problem

Comment: I don't understand how this could solve the issue. Not removing the newline would just be caught by the `except` block and print `"This is a string"` instead of triggering the error.

Comment: I don't think that code will raise error with exception handling, This error would be raised without exception handing. Error can be solved by removing '\n'.

Comment: Yes...but the code the OP posted has the `try` and `except` blocks around the `datetime` parsing, which is why the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Can't believe something like this would solve the error :)